# subscript out of bounds Error, Random Forest Model

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to use the random forest model to predict Gender based on Height, Weight and Number of siblings. I've gotten the data from a much larger data set that contains dozens of variables, but I've cleaned it into this "clean" data.frame with omitted NA values and only the 4 variables I care about, the last column being Gender.

I've tried fiddling with the code and searching everywhere but I can't find a concrete fix.

Here's the code:

```
ind <- sample(nrow(clean),0.8*nrow(clean))
train <- clean[ind,]
test <- clean[-ind,]


rf <- randomForest(Gender ~ ., data = train[,1:4], ntree = 20)

pred <- predict(rf, newdata = test[,-c(length(test))])
cm <- table(test$Gender, pred)
cm
```

and here's the output:

```
Error in `[.default`(table(observed = y, predicted = out.class), levels(y), : subscript out of bounds
Traceback:

1. randomForest(Gender ~ ., data = train[, 1:4], ntree = 20)
2. randomForest.formula(Gender ~ ., data = train[, 1:4], ntree = 20)
3. randomForest.default(m, y, ...)
4. table(observed = y, predicted = out.class)[levels(y), levels(y)]
5. `[.table`(table(observed = y, predicted = out.class), levels(y), 
 .     levels(y))
6. NextMethod()
```

Comment: Can you give us some idea what is in `clean` ?

Comment: clean has 4 columns of about a thousand rows each: height (in centimeters), weight (in kilograms), number of siblings (integer), and Gender ("male" or "female").

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you have some kind of a variable level in your test data that was not reflected in your training data. So when it goes to assign the outcome, it has no basis to do so.

It is impossible to say for sure without sample data, but it is the most likely scenario. Try setting a seed `set.seed=3` and then change the seed number `set.seed=28` and so on, a few times to see if you end up finding a combination where you do not get the error.

Compare the conflicted data frame with the un-conflicted one to see what is missing.

**EDIT:**

Also, try running `str(train)` and `str(test)` to be sure the fields have remained the same. You can share that if you like by editing your post.

If any of the columns are factors with levels missing (meaning it has 10 levels but only 8 are represented in the train with 9 or 10 in the test) it might be a problem. They should be balanced if you are trying to create a predictor for all possible outcomes.

If nothing else works, you can set a seed and remove predictors one at a time until it runs correctly, then look to see how the train and test sets are different in that removed column.

Comment: How can I see the conflicted data frame? Do you mean the differences between train and clean, to check if there are some values missing? I tried several different seed values and none of them panned out so far. Do you think it has something to do with the fact that there are several different heights and weights, and some might not appear in both the train set and the test set?

Comment: Set each seeded test and train set with a suffix, `train_22` , `test_22` that tells you the seed. That way you have the set saved in memory. Then if you are using R studio, on the environment panel on the right, click on the name of the data frame and it will open up in a tabbed window where your script is. If you would rather, you can `write.csv(test_22, "failed.csv")` and  `write.csv(test_3, "passed.csv")` then you can open them up in Excel and look at the columns to see if you are missing an outcome in train, so that you cannot predict it in test.